# ServiceStack: Adding routes dynamically

Tags: servicestack

I have not tried this yet, but I would like each module (Silverlight) to register its own routes, rather then adding it in application start.

**Can routes be added to AppHost after application start, or do they all have to be immediatelly registered during Configure step?**

I am thinking to scan all assemblies at the startup and provide AppHost with all assemblies that  implement service stack services, but let each module add its own routes (have not figured out yet exact mechanism.

Before I go down this route, need to know if it is possible to add routes after the Configure step.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All configuration and registration in [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net) should be done within the `AppHost.Configure()` method and remain immutable thereafter.

If you want to encapsulate registrations of routes in a module than package it as a [Plugin](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Plugins) and register them manually on `IPlugin.Register(IAppHost)`.

Here are some different ways to register routes:

```
public class MyModule : IPlugin
{
    public void Register(IAppHost appHost)
    {
        appHost.Routes.Add<MyRequestDto>("/myservice", "POST PUT");

        appHost.Routes.Add(typeof(MyRequestDto2), "/myservice2", "GET");

        appHost.RegisterService(typeof(MyService), "/myservice3"); 
    }
}
```

Then inside your AppHost.Configure you would register the Plugin, e.g:

```
Plugins.Add(new MyModule());
```

Comment: When registring routes, in AppHost, generic parameter was a request type, but here it is a service?

Comment: @epitka updated, RegisterService takes a Service type whereas, Routes.Add takes a Request DTO type