# Authentication on dynamically added route

Tags: authentication, servicestack

There are an option in ServiceStack to [add routes dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245203/servicestack-adding-routes-dynamically), using `IAppHost.Routes.Add`. This is quite handy as it allows reusable services to be packed in a form of plugin and attached to actual applications.

To illustrate, here's an excerpt of application host configuration that enables a plugin and attaches routes:

```
class AppHost: AppHostHttpListenerBase {
    public override void Configure(Container container) {
        // other stuff
        Plugins.Add(new MyReusablePlugin());
        Routes.Add(typeof(string), "/stuff", "GET");
        Routes.Add(typeof(string), "/other-stuff", "POST");
    }
}
```

The problem is, I can't find a way to specify that authentication is required for those dynamically added routes. As of ServiceStack `4.0.15` there are no overload to `Routes.Add` that allow specifying that those routes require authentication. Is it possible (maybe in newer versions)?

Ideally, such a mechanism should support specifying roles/permissions, just like `RequiredRoleAttribue` or `RequiresAnyRoleAttribute`.

One more thing: I'm aware of Global request filters and it looks like they are a bit too global to be a valid solution here, but I might be wrong. If it's possible to achieve the same result (including ability to specify required roles/permissions) using request filters I would be glad to accept an example of such apporach as an answer.

Comment: John, any luck using the `AddAttributes` extension method of `Type`?

Comment: @Scott, sorry, I've been dragged into other tasks. I'll let you know as soon as I have a chance to revisit this (next week I hope)

Comment: Hi John similarly if you could let me know about this one if it's sorted. :) Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the [`AddAttributes` extension method](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Text/ReflectionExtensions.cs) provided on `Type`:

```cs
typeof(YourType).AddAttributes(new RequiredRoleAttribute("Admin"));
```

So you would need to do this in addition to the `Routes.Add` method.

Comment: @J0HN That's great. Thanks for helping me over the 10K :)